# Get compressed+uncompressed size of URL response in Chrome extension/app

Tags: javascript, http, compression, google-chrome-app

I'm writing a Chrome packaged app. Given any URL, I need my app to send a GET request to the URL and display how many KB the compressed and uncompressed response sent back is (eg example.com returns 50KB of compressed data that is 80KB when uncompressed). How would I code this in JavaScript?

Typical AJAX calls just give you the uncompressed data back but don't tell you the size of the compressed data. I've tried looking for a Chrome app API to help but decompression appears to be transparently handled for you and you're not given access to the uncompressed size.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. This will help getting useful answers

Comment: @Ulrich Seems like a perfectly reasonable question to me that doesn't need touch-ups except for tags.

Comment: Try sending two requests: with `Accept-Encoding: gzip` header and without.  And maybe it'll be even possible to use `HEAD` method instead of `GET` to have the info.

Comment: [Chrome Canary landed support for {transfer, encodedBody, decodedBody}size Resource Timing attributes](https://plus.google.com/+IlyaGrigorik/posts/TrPQx3wA127).